# How to scale with proportion with N panel?

Tags: transforms

Pressing S to scale it goes in proportion but it shows in which measurement I don't know. With the N panel, it shows the dimension for example 10cm, How can I scale with proportion by inserting the value?

For example, I want to scale to a proportion of 10cm down or up to an exact value. How it will work, any suggestions or help? Thanks

Comment: in blender you dont scale by adding or removing a dimension, pressing S will allow you to create a multiplier, for example pressing S, then 2 will double the dimensions, if you go to the yellow button with a square in a shape it will give you the same contents as the n page, also you can type mathematical opperator for example after any value if you add *2 or +2 it will multiply the value by 2 or add 2, this works with many different operators

Answer (score 1):

One way to scale in proportion to a given dimension in X,Y or Z:

- Enter the desired dimension in the 'Dimensions' panel
- Go up to the scale panel, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> copy the scale from that axis
- Swipe the 'Scale' fields, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> paste

[image]

.. followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply Scale.

If you're working to, say, an edge-length, not a major dimension, find the existing length, using, say, the 'MeasureIt' shipped add-on, type "`new_length` / `old_length`" (substituted) into one of the scale fields, and copy-paste as above.